# Difference in colors between Sketch and iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sketchapp

Please, can you explain me why I do have so big difference in the colors between my sketch design and what I see on my iphone simulator? In this case, I was using background picture from sketch and it was not changed at all but the difference is huge. How can I make it look the same?

[image]

Comment: how do you use this color inside the app?

Comment: It is just a picture of the background. let imageViewBg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "MenuBg"))
        tableView.backgroundView = imageViewBg

Comment: Have you tried to reopen saved image in macos preview? It might be that you saved this file in web-safe colors.

Comment: Vyacheslav do you speak Russian? ;)

Comment: Yes, I can. But this forum is in English. Use https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ to ask in Russian.

Comment: No English is fine. Yes I did open image on my mac and it looks like on my iPhone simulator not like on the sketch. The funny thing I used colour picker to get background colour from sketch image and placed it into the code and it is still a huge difference. Is it possible that sketch does not show correct colours?

Comment: Try to change a color scheme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess may be a problem related to the [color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space), [Sketch documentation](https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/other/color-management/) and [here](https://sketchtalk.io/discussion/2247/sketch-doesnt-do-color-management-and-why-thats-a-bad-idea). So basically Sketch uses by default the `Unmanaged color profile`, which means your system’s default color profile — ‘Color LCD’ on a MacBook Pro for example:

[image]

Instead on Xcode you should have `sRGB IEC61966-2.1`, to be able to change the color you should touch the color selection of the `UIView` that you have to modify, eg:

1. here the color selection:

[image]

2. then you should see this cake:

[image]

3. touch on the second button on the top bar

[image]

4. then you'll have the possibility to change the color space:

[image]

Of course it's possible to do the same thing by code, since you have to mess with `CGColorSpaceModel` and [color transformations,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace) it's just a bit more verbose.

---

So, before to export (Sketch) and run on simulator (Xcode), a solution might be check to have selected on both applications the same color space:  `sRGB IEC61966-2.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did set up it in Sketch. How can I do it in my Xcode?